# Speed up apply in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

df:

```
Person,utility,selected,innovation
2012001153_7_E02005533_1_2012002698,130.2333,yes,0
2012001153_7_E02005533_1_2012002698,110.33,no,1
2012001153_7_E02005533_1_2012002698,83,no,2
2012001153_7_E02005533_1_2012002698,-100,no,3
2012001153_7_E02005533_1_2012002698,49,no,4
```

I wish to create a new column where I find the relative dis utility to that selected "i.e. when selected == "yes"".

The following works but is slow when doing this on millions of records:

```
def get_relativeUtilityToSelected(group):
    selected_utility = group[group['selected']=='yes']['utility'].values[0]
    group['relativeDisUtilityToSelected'] = group['utility'] - selected_utility
    return group

df = df.groupby(['person']).apply(get_relativeUtilityToSelected)
```

Expected output:

```
Person,utility,selected,innovation,relativeDisUtilityToSelected
2012001153_7_E02005533_1_2012002698,130.2333,yes,0,0
2012001153_7_E02005533_1_2012002698,110.33,no,1,-19.9033
2012001153_7_E02005533_1_2012002698,83,no,2,-47.2333
2012001153_7_E02005533_1_2012002698,-100,no,3,-230.2333
2012001153_7_E02005533_1_2012002698,49,no,4,-81.2333
```

How may I speed this up?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a speed issue, you should avoid using `.apply` altogether, as it's going to loop over your DataFrame.

Note: from your function, I infer that each 'person' only has one and one only row where `'selected' == 'yes'`.

That should do it:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

ds = """person,utility,selected,innovation
2012001153_7_E02005533_1_2012002698,130.2333,yes,0
2012001153_7_E02005533_1_2012002698,110.33,no,1
2012001153_7_E02005533_1_2012002698,83,no,2
2012001153_7_E02005533_1_2012002698,-100,no,3
2012001153_7_E02005533_1_2012002698,49,no,4"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(ds))

df['relativeDisUtility'] = df['utility'] - df[df['selected'] == 'yes'][['person', 'utility']].set_index('person').loc[df['person']].values[:, 0]

df
```

Result:

```
                                person  ...  relativeDisUtility
0  2012001153_7_E02005533_1_2012002698  ...              0.0000
1  2012001153_7_E02005533_1_2012002698  ...            -19.9033
2  2012001153_7_E02005533_1_2012002698  ...            -47.2333
3  2012001153_7_E02005533_1_2012002698  ...           -230.2333
4  2012001153_7_E02005533_1_2012002698  ...            -81.2333
```

Decompisition:

```py
df[
    df['selected'] == 'yes'  # pick the rows where 'selected' == 'yes'
][
    ['person', 'utility']    # choose 'person' and 'utility' columns
].set_index(
    'person'                 # make 'person' the index
).loc[
    df['person']             # expand to the shape of the original 'person' column
].values[:, 0]               # get the values
```